# javax.persistence.PersistenceException in google app engine connected android project

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I created Google app engine connected android project. When I run my code i got this exception. Could any one tell how can i come through this problem. Thanks alot

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
 {
   "code" : 503,
 "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for \"JPATest\" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl",
   "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No persistence providers available for \"JPATest\" after trying the following discovered implementations: org.datanucleus.api.jpa.PersistenceProviderImpl"